# Export the Infopath Repeating table to Excel

Tags: infopath, forms-services, infopath-data-connections

I am having bunch of rows in the repeating table and I am fetching this based on some dropdown box conditions.Now my client is expecting to get the repeating table data into excel sheet.Can any one help me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Open XML SDK** to programmatically create an Excel workbook on the server in SharePoint. You should write a program that makes use of **SpreadsheetDocument** objects.

There is no direct function or feature in SharePoint or InfoPath that can help you export the repeating table data to Excel. The goal here is to get the repeating table data into Excel and that could be achieved by programming with **Open XML SDK**.

You can refer this article [Generating Excel 2010 Workbooks by using the Open XML SDK 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on MSDN to get started with using the **Open XML SDK** to write code that can create an Excel workbook.

Using data from a repeating table on an InfoPath form to create an Excel workbook that contains data on one of its spreadsheets then becomes a matter of programmatically looping through the rows and cells of the repeating table in InfoPath and then creating corresponding rows and cells with data on the Excel spreadsheet.

To loop through items in a repeating table of InfoPath you can refer this article: [How to loop through items in a repeating table in InfoPath 2007](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/loop-through-items-repeating-table.htm)
(I am not sure about the version of InfoPath you are using but I know this looping code can help you in InfoPath 2010 and 2013 both).